# Multiselect dropdown select and deselect issue in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-chosen

I am using multi select dropdown to select multiple options.when i try to add multiple usernames it is working fine. when i try to deselect the one of the selected usernames from dropdown from UI it is looks like it is removing but from code level deselected username is not removed.
Anyone can me help me to solve this issue.i am using below code for multiselect dropdown.

```
<div id="dvUserNames" class="col-md-6">
@if (Model.UserNameCollection != null)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserId, 
                          new SelectList(Model.UserNameCollection, "UserId", "UserName", Model.UserId), 
                          new { @class = "chosen-select", multiple = "multiple", @style = "width:6.0cm"                               
                         })
}
</div>
```

i am using below code in jquery button click event.

```
  var UserNameCollection=[]; 
    for (var i = 0; i < $('#dvUserNames :selected').length; i++) 
{ 
UserNameCollection.push($('#dvUserNames :selected')[i].value); 
}
```

[MultiSelect DropDown Deselected Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvgKo.png)

Thank you
Venkateswara rao

Comment: What do you mean "from code level"?  Where specifically are you observing this result?  What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Code in comments is not very useful.  Please update the question to include relevant code and indicate specifically what is failing.  If the problem is being observed in the JavaScript, you should also update the question to include a runnable code snippet of the JavaScript in question and the resulting client-side HTML on which that JavaScript operates.

Comment: `class = "chosen-select"` are you converting it to a [tag:jquery-chosen] box?  or just using the styling?   If using [tag:jquery-chosen] then you need to use its API.

Comment: @Venkateswararao: Where are you using the shown JavaScript code?  Is this just happening once when the page loads?  Or in response to a specific event?  It's important to provide a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @David i am using javascript code in button click event.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing to the array when you add a record, but you need to splice the user array when it is deselected

```
UserNameCollection.splice([Index of removed username]);
```

Comment: is there any event for deselect time.i tried with onchange event but it will call every time select or deselect time.how to know whether it is select or deselected.can you please help me.

Comment: you could do a comparison in the onchange handler

Comment: e.g. if `UserNameCollection` contains a record that is not in ```$('#dvUserNames :selected')```, slice it from `UserNameCollection`

Comment: OP stated they run their code on a button click, so there would be no existing array to splice.  A [mcve] snippet would make this clear.

Comment: how to get deseleted item index or text. i tried by using chosen-updated trigger. it also not helped.

Comment: @freedomn-m in the initial response to my answer he has said he tried with an onchange event. Looking at his example, you can't see what the trigger is so it is hard to provide a reproducible example when this has not been provided initially.

Comment: @DrollDread agreed that it needs more info from OP